# RInside segmentation fault and linking issue

Tags: c++, r, rinside

I'm trying to call R from c++ on linux via RInside, I compiled R-2.15.1 from source with gcc version 4.5.3 (Debian 4.5.3-1) , I don't have sudo rights to use apt-get install. I'm using OpenBlas and a system optimized lapack. The blas and lapack libraries work fine for many scalapack applications

I installed R with

```
./configure --with-blas="-I/lib/OpenBLAS-v0.2.3-0/xianyi-OpenBLAS-48f075c/install/include -L/lib/OpenBLAS-v0.2.3-0/xianyi-OpenBLAS-48f075c/install/lib -lopenblas -lgfortran" --with-lapack="/usr/lib/liblapack.so -lgfortran" --enable-BLAS-shlib=yes --enable-R-shlib --enable-R-static-lib --prefix= .
```

which installed and runs fine,I ran make check with no errors, also all the packages (Rcpp and RInside) installed fine..

however when i use the given RInside `makefile` , the basic hello world example from `/standard/rinside_sample0.cpp` compiles! but it does not run and i get the following error

```
./rinside_sample0: error while loading shared libraries: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the file `libRblas.so` exists and is in the `R/lib` folder,

when i try to link it manually with the g++ command the make file creates or linking as follows i get a segmentation fault

```
/R/lib/libRblas.so ./hello_world
Segmentation fault
```

EDIT:  heres how the example make file tries to compile an example, (which compiles fine) but won't run with the above missing `libRblas.so` error

```
g++ -I/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/include -I/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/RInside/include -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include   hello_world.cpp  -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/lib -lR  -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib -L/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/nfs/user03/jimmie21/libs/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib -o hello_world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the R install path lib `../R/lib:` to the beginning of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after that all the examples compiled and run fine

Comment: Good to know. I think it is more common to update / edit the question that to add a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

1. Reproducible examples, please
2. You have a non-standard setup
3. With the script from 1), try it on a standard setting as that is how Rcpp / RInside get developed and tested (on Ubuntu / Debian)
4. The Rcpp test suite now contains almost 800 unit tests from around 350 unit test functions. These do not seg.fault, so the issue is at your end. Similarly, RInside has dozens of examples in the four `examples/` subdirectories. This also works.

It may be as easy as tweaking the Makefile / Makevars files to make sure you get your libraries in all cases.  But we can't tell as there is nothing reproducible here.

*Edit*  If you want to link with `libRblas.so` then you have a *completely* non-standard setup as the R packages for Debian / Ubuntu as use the external BLAS.   Again, not an RInside issue.

Comment: I thought it was just a simple linking issue, since all the packages installed fine,the problem is I can only install everything from source is there a suggested blas/lapack library I should be using?

Comment: I don't have root privileges for `apt-get`